# Hourly Data On Highchart Not starting with 0 tick

Tags: angular, highcharts, timezone

I have implemented highchart and i am working in the DAY resolution mode. In DAY mode i want to show data from 0-24. Now every things works well without adding the time zone.

Please click on this below link to see the snippet of what i am doing.

> [How to show data for the Hour in Highchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631626/how-to-show-data-for-the-hour-in-highchart?noredirect=1#comment76286614_44631626)

But, after adding the timezone my start tick is not starting with 0.

```
 Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    getTimezoneOffset: function (timestamp) {
                        return -moment.tz(timestamp, timezoneName).utcOffset();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Normal Condition:(without integrating the timezone code)
[image]

Time Zone: Europe/Berlin (Tick started from 2 instead of 0)   [image]

Time Zone : Asia/Kolkata [image]

So, what i observed that the TimeZone in which i am rendering the highchart its taking the offset of that zone and rendering it on the chart.

I am using min and max to set the x-axis label:

```
 this.highchartsConfiguration.xAxis.min = Date.UTC(dateSelected.getFullYear(),
                dateSelected.getMonth(), dateSelected.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
            this.highchartsConfiguration.xAxis.max = Date.UTC(dateSelected.getFullYear(),
                dateSelected.getMonth(), dateSelected.getDate(), 23, 59, 0);
```

Can anybody help me how i can set the label to 0 in every timezone scenario.
I dont want to use setUTC : true or false. As i am using the timezone concept here.

Comment: Have you tried to set min value on xAxis with the fixed time? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ybj38ks8/ It seems to work.